# What is the weakest steroid in systemic usage?

Tags: dermatology, side-effects, allergy, steroids, safety

I understand that there are several steroids given as a systemic treatment in various doses and at various day times (morning or evening) adjusted by patient situation<sup>[(1)](https://dermnetnz.org/topics/systemic-steroids)</sup>.

For example:

- Prednisone
- Prednisolone
- Methylprednisolone
- Beclomethasone
- Betamethasone
- Dexamethasone
- Hydrocortisone
- Triamcinolone

According to this article one might think that Hydrocortisone is at least a "weak" one<sup>[(2)](https://www.nhs.uk/medicines/hydrocortisone-tablets/)</sup>.

But is there a "weakest" steroid among these (or another)?
Weakest by any mean; challenges in blood stream, low receptor affinity or anything else.

Comment: You have the right idea in differing "weakness" by effects, but it's [not quite that simple.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5216559/)